# how to pass form as parameter to the function of dll created in c# in delphi 5

Tags: delphi

how to pass delphi form as parameter to the function of dll created in c#. I want to pass form as a argument to the function. 
Error is: 
incompatible types: 'Class reference' and '_Form'

c# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace s3
{
    //g1b572e8-7888-47e4-98t1-fe0e15855r32

    [Guid("e1b572e8-7888-47e4-98e1-fe0e15855f49"),InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface setmonitorwindow
    {
         void Concatenate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] Form f1);
    }



    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f2 = this;

            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            c1.Concatenate(f2);

        }
    }




    [Guid("76663fdc-8bb8-4e68-82j5-a110aa3c0uf2"),ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1 : setmonitorwindow
    {


        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
     public void Concatenate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] Form f1) //this function i wan call
        {

            var screen1 = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
            f1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            f1.Left = screen1.Bounds.Left + screen1.Bounds.Width / 2 - f1.Width / 2;
            f1.Top = screen1.Bounds.Top + screen1.Bounds.Height / 2 - f1.Height / 2;

        }
    }
}
```

delphi code:

```
begin
    objsetmonitor := CoClass1.Create;
    objsetmonitor.Concatenate(TForm1);  
    Form2.Show;
end;
```

I tried other way also as specified by DavidHeffernan Sir as follows:

i implement following code :

```
    Function MonitorFromWindow(hwnd: HWND;dwFlags:DWORD):HWND; stdcall; external 'User32.dll';
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
       result:=MonitorFromWindow(Form3.Handle,MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
       Form3.Show;
end;
```

but now MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST is undeclared identifier in delphi 5 how to declare it. and please also tell me is i m going in right way?

Comment: What are you going to do with that form in you c# dll?

Comment: to get form open on same monitor on which cursor is present.

Comment: You cannot access your form parameter from c#. It is a Delphi class instance and that is not compatible with a c# class instance. Why don't you add the logic to your delphi code? It's just a few lines of code.

Comment: i am new in delphi. and version on which i am working is delphi 5. i will be great full  if you give me a example to to this. as FromPoint is not in delphi 5

Comment: This is the height of folly. Call the Win32 API from Delphi. Call `MonitorFromPoint`.

Comment: @David - Delphi 5 does not directly provide **Screen.MonitorFromPoint** which is not a simple wrapper around any single Win32 Api.  There may not be much work involved to implement it, but looking at the supporting scaffolding behind that simple function in later Delphi versions it's debatable whether the C# solution is not at least comparable in effort (especially if the OP is more comfortable/competent in C#)

Comment: I could not disagree more @deltics. Bringing .net into the process just to find out which monitor a point is on? Requiring COM registration as currently implemented. You think that is preferable to calling a Win32 API. If you don't know something, learn it.

Comment: I said it was *debatable*.  I didn't say that I knew what the outcome of any such debate might be.  It surprises me not in the slightest however that you disagree with there being even any need for "debate" (by which of course I mean consideration on the part of the OP in light of the OP's actual position about which *we* do not know everything).  You are of course always right.

Comment: @Deltics I'm not always right. But I am right here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you sir for calling me that. yes i am also agree you are always right. My kind request to you please do not take efforts to provide solution or your valuable guidance on my questions.

Comment: It's clearly pointless isn't it. Pride can be very difficult to overcome. Obviously I cannot help you, because you don't want to learn how to call `MonitorFromPoint`. Something that is actually trivial. But as for providing solutions to questions that you ask, I will do as I please. Remember that this site isn't for personal individual support. If you ask a good question that has value for others, I will feel quite free to comment and answer on it. If you don't want to listen, then you can just ignore me. It works that way round.

Comment: Yes sir thank you again for telling that this is not individual site. I thought people who are not expert in any technology but wanted to learn it from the expert around the word what they tried to implement. But sometime expertise comes with arrogance. Yes i am not expert in delphi but trying to learn it and Stack overflow helps where i stuck down, that's why coder like me come here to ask questions. Yes you can comment, after all that was my kind request in kind words. I will not going to comment on this topic again. Thanks to comment on my pointless  comment.

Comment: Why did you select the worst solution rather than trying to learn? Calling two winapi functions is not hard?

Comment: I tried for you suggestion also. like wise i updated the question please check it. @DavidHeffernan

Comment: I think that the jedi headers will have the code you need. Or you could translate yourself from the windows sdk.

Comment: I created one sample same as my Application. in that sample in aftercreateform function setwindowpos is called to set windows potion. in sample application when i commented this line it will solve the dual monitor issue but when i comment same in my original application it wont work. following line i used to comment                                                     
SetWindowPos(self.Handle, HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,  SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Delphi **Form** is an instance of a *Delphi class*, not a *.NET framework class*.  As such there is nothing meaningful that any C# code is going to be able to do with any such form reference.

However, what you are trying to achieve does not require the form object, only the window handle of the desktop window that the form represents.

Rewrite your C# code to accept a **HWND** and pass the `Form.WindowHandle` to the C#.  You may then need to use interop to call the appropriate Win32 API functions to work with that window handle.

Having said that, what you are trying to achieve should be straightforward in the Delphi application concerned itself, with no need to involve any external code, let alone C#, at all.  The only complication being that your Delphi version (*Delphi 5*) does not directly support a **MonitorFromPoint()** method.

Implementing one would not be especially difficult but if you are more comfortable in the C# space then this might be a reason to continue down your current path (but using a **HWND**) unless you can get help with implementing the required code in Delphi.

Comment: Yes @Deltics, I changed my c# code as you told. And pass handle as argument to c# dll from my delphi 5 code. It wroks for me. Thanks a lot. at last i got the solution. :)

Comment: will you please tell me how to implement MonitorFromPoint() method in delphi 5 @Deltics

Comment: i called in this way  AutoVueObj.Concatenate(self.WindowHandle);  function of through dll implemented in c# but it gives error that type error is cannot marshal parameter Invalid manage/unmanaged type combination @Deltics

Comment: function in c# code is changed in this way                                         
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        public void Concatenate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] IntPtr hWnd)  //LPWStr               @Deltics